# Focus blur on client routing ideal for SPAs?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have a single page application. There is a page with products and on the bottom a link to go to the next page. Upon clicking this "next" link the list of products in the DOM is replaced. While the link clicked has stayed the same and maintains focus from the click. Is it better for me to do something like `document.activeElement.blur()` is that case? Or should I just leave focus on that as is?

I'm unsure what best practice is as with normal server routed pages the focus would be reset with the page load. But I haven't seen any information indicating manually resetting focus on client routing would be the best experience from an accessibility point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever use blur. It's just bad, random and possibly frustrating.

IN a native application, you should always exactly know where the focus is, and the focus should always be at a precise place; otherwise keyboard accessibility is broken.
If you consider your web application as being a true application, you should observe the same rigour.

So, never use blur, since you don't know at all where the focus is going to move afterwards. If you are going to remove something from the DOM that currently has focus, you should first place it in another place that make sense.

IN your case: clicking on a link, you have two reasonable options:

- Leave the focus on the link (reasonable as long as you don't move, hide or remove it from the DOM)
- Move the focus at the beginning of the new content that just appeared / has just been replaced

You may ask users of your application which solution they think is the best, or deduce the answer by observing them during a test session.

Let's summarize quickly: whether you are making an old-style website with different pages, and you don't have to matter much about focus, or you are making a real **application** and in that case you should be as rigourous as if you were developing a native app.
Terribly simple.